# Filter a list with streams based on ids from another list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of `Product` objects with 30 objects.

I have created a fix list with strings of ids.

`List<String> productsIdsForFreeSchoolYear = Arrays.asList("169", "172", "198", "213", "358", "4529", "6602", "5958");`

What I want to do is to get list of `Product` only contains the ids from `productsIdsForFreeSchoolYear` list.

This is what i tried, but its seems its only check if the ids exists? Im i right?

```
productsSelectable.stream()
                .distinct()
                .filter(productsIdsForFreeSchoolYear::contains)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`productsSelectable` is the list of `Product`.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: *.filter(p -> productsIdsForFreeSchoolYear.contains(p.getProductId()))*, if you have a way to get product id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `contains()` will always return `false` because it's a list of IDs (strings), and you're passing it a Product instance. You probably want something like this:

```
productsSelectable.stream()
            .distinct()
            .filter(p -> productsIdsForFreeSchoolYear.contains(p.getId()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Its not working, i get a Product with id `3591` which is not in the `productsIdsForFreeSchoolYear ` list.

Comment: @mac187 you need to explain better, what is not working with an example in that case and as an improvement with `contains` you can change the type of the `productsIdsForFreeSchoolYear` to a `Set<String>` over a `List`. Besides, you might want to perform `distinct` after `filter` as well.